# Android MotionLayout custom attribute methodName

Tags: android, android-motionlayout

What is the usage of custom attribute in MotionLayout "methodName"?
an example will be great :-)

I'm looking for a good solution for cases where I've a textView and I need to change the fontFamily or gravity when it's not supported by MotionLayout.

Answer (score 0):

MethodName and custom method allows you to call Methods that are not in the standard set and get
Usually associated with

for example:

```xml
 <KeyTrigger motion:framePosition="60"
                motion:motionTarget="@+id/button"  motion:onNegativeCross=".">
                <CustomMethod motion:methodName="performHapticFeedback"   motion:customIntegerValue="3"/>
            </KeyTrigger>
```

Generally the TextView is not design with animation and would not give you what you are looking for.

For example gravity,  Change it would not animate the text to the new position because they are positions

Animation of FontFamily etc is also not easy.
To change things like that you really have 2 choices:

1. Cross fading between two textView
2. Use MotionLabel which is limited but was designed with animation in mine.

**MotionLabel**

MotionLabel has the limitation of only supporting a single line of text
But provides a rich set of attributes you can use to animate

for example instead of gravity with its limited "start" "center" etc.
It supports textPanX and textPanY where textPanX=0.0 is center, -1.0 is left justified, and +1.0 right justified.
allowing you to smoothly pan from center to left.

It also support scaleFromTextSize to allow you to set a base text size which the text will scale from.  Animating the text size will cause loading a different font on each frame.

For more information on MotionLabel the see the [GitHub](https://github.com/androidx/constraintlayout/wiki/MotionLabel)